# React Localization - Internationalize with i18next

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, i18next, react-i18next

I want to add to language in project.

I use i18next . i add i18n.js

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
// Importing translation files

import translationEN from "./locales/en/translation.json";
import translationFA from "./locales/fa/translation.json";


 //Creating object with the variables of imported translation files
const resources = {
en: {
    translation: translationEN,
},
fa: {
    translation: translationFA,
},
};

//i18N Initialization

i18n
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
    resources,
    lng: "fa", //default language
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
    },
});

export default i18n;
```

add import it in index

```
import "./i18n"
```

add use in login

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

function Login(props) {
const { t } = useTranslation();
var classes = useStyles();
...
  <Typography variant="h1" className={classes.greeting}>
                          {t('Login')}
  </Typography>
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

when i run it, i dont get any error but show blank page.

Comment: Are you sure that its a react-i18n issue? What happens if you remove the import?

Comment: when i remove `useTranslation ` , show page

Comment: i use this in empty project, it work ok. but when i add this in my project show empty page

Comment: compare with: https://locize.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-i18next/